# Installing coursera-dl in Canopy

Tags: python, canopy

I installed Canopy 64-bit on a Windows 8 machine. I am trying to install an external package called coursera-dl (https://github.com/dgorissen/coursera-dl). I get the following error using pip:

[image: Canopty error]

Can someone please help me out? I tried searching other articles here but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the trouble. This is a bug in Canopy 1.3 on Windows-64 which should be fixed in Canopy 1.4 next week. Meanwhile, the workaround is to start with:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I opened a Canopy command prompt and typed the command you suggested. Then I typed: "easy_install coursera-dl" and it installed correctly. Thanks!